# JSHint with RequireJS and AngularJS: functions / objects "is not defined"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, jshint

I have an AngularJS application with RequireJS and JSHint. There I have a controller `MyCtrl`:

```
define([
    'myDependecy'
], function(app) {
    'use strict';
    app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
        doSomething();
        var test = MyTest.doIt();
    });
});
```

`myDependency` is a JavaScript file which has following content:

```
var MyTest = (function() {
    var doIt = function() {
        // …
    };
    return {
        doIt: doIt
    }
});

function doSomething() {
    console.log("test");
}
```

The problem with JSHint is that I get the error messages `'MyTest' is not defined` and also `'doSomething' is not defined`. What can I do to solve this problem, because they are defined but JSHint don't know it.

**Update**

The problem seems to be the mix of AMD and Non-AMD modules. So the best solution in this case won't be the `/* global … */` comment.

**Update2**

The problem occurs also in `grunt serve:dist` which generates one big JavaScript file. So the problem is more "complex". The real problem has one more dependency. The `MyTest` object literal is here:

```
(function(root) {
    define("test1", ["test2"], function() {
        return (function() {
            var MyTest = (function () {
                // …
            }());
        }).apply(root, arguments);
    });
}(this));
```

And the implementation with the `doIt` is defined in a similar `define` block named `test2` where the error occurs.

Comment: You can add `/*global MyTest*/` to tell JSHint about the variable.

Comment: It works. So this is the solution or is it possible to do it in a better way?

Comment: This is not how you're supposed to use RequireJS; you're mixing AMD and non-AMD modules. If MyDependency followed AMD format the JSHint warnings would simply go away. Relevant documentation: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define

Comment: I updated the original post, because doing a ``grunt serve:dist`` it will be wrapped. Also I thought in my ``main.js`` I have in ``require.congig`` a ``shim``section with ``test1: { deps: ['test2']}``. I think building with ``grunt serve:dist`` it is wrapped based on this configurations.